# GoogleSignIn in Firebase Test Lab: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I would like to inquire if the shack has passed or has the solution to this situation.

The Beta APP performs the authentication correctly, however when running tests in the Firebase Test Lab I always receive the authenticity failure along with the warning:

> com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501